# Is $\cos (2\theta) $ two-fold symmetric?

Tags: trigonometry, symmetry

I read that $\cos (2 \theta)$ is two-fold symmetric about cartesian coordinate system ? Is that true , if so how ?

Answer (score 0):

It's $\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$, which is unchanged under $x\mapsto -x$ or $y\mapsto -y$.

Comment: This could use a bit more explanation to be really useful.  At least to me, I don't see how it answers the question (granted the question is a bit unclear to me as well).

Comment: @TravisJ I think the two-fold symmetry sought in the question is reflection in each Cartesian axis, which is demonstrated by rewriting $\cos 2\theta$ as a function of $x,\,y$.